# How can i resolve my bootstrap issue in Angular cli

Tags: angularjs

ERROR in multi ../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css ./src/styles.css
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\Users\NAVEEN.MULAGA\AngularProjects\node_modules\bootstrap\dist\css\bootstrap.min.css'

Answer (score 3):

`import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';` is referencing the file from node_modules.

You are getting this error because your module is missing.

You just have to simply command `npm install bootstrap` to put it back in your node_modules.

Answer (score 1):

In your `angular.json` file ensure that you have added:

> node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css

under projects->architect->build->styles

> node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js

under projects->architect->build->scripts array